# Wordpress counting posts wrong

Tags: wordpress, counting

What I'm trying to do:
The posts can be categorized as A or B types. And I want to do an Archive that counts how many posts are categorized as A, how many are in B, and the total.

The problem:
My code counts like 12 posts for category A. It counts 5 for category B. But it counts 12 for both category.

Why?

My code:

```
$posts_a = new WP_Query('cat=5&category__and=30');
$count_a = $posts_a->post_count;
//gives 12

$posts_b = new WP_Query('cat=5&category__and=29');
$count_b = $posts_b->post_count;
//gives 5

$posts_all = new WP_Query('cat=5');
$count_all = $posts_all->post_count;
//gives 12. It should be at least 12+5.
```

I don't want just to sum A+B. I want to know what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Do any of your posts overlap? That is, are in both categories?

Comment: You mean, a post in category A and B at same time? No :(. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have just two categories, looking at your queries. 
From what I can, there are three categories, A, B and C.

There are 12 posts in categories A and B, and 5 in categories A and C, from what I can see from your queries and results.

You are also using category__and incorrectly, which may be the cause of the confusion.

Can you tell me what are the two category IDs you are searching for? I will post the queries after you mention them.

Edit: You probably need this:

```
$posts_a = new WP_Query(array('category__and'=>array(5,30),'posts_per_page'=>-1));
$count_a = $posts_a->post_count;

$posts_b = new WP_Query(array('category__and'=>array(5,29),'posts_per_page'=>-1));
$count_b = $posts_b->post_count;

$posts_all = new WP_Query('cat=5&posts_per_page=-1');
$count_all = $posts_all->post_count;
```

Also, this is probably an obvious answer and I don't know your category structure, but is 29 a child category of 30?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yeah, the website could have a lot of categories (like IDs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...), but all of them must be categorized as A (ID 30) or B (ID 29).
The Archive of ID 5 should show:
1) posts with ID 5 also categorized as A (ID 30).
2) posts with ID 5 also categorized as B (ID 29).
3) all posts with ID 5 (should include posts categorized as A, as B and even that one who I forget to categorize as A or B).

ID 5 and A are returning me 12.
ID 5 and B are returning me 5.
all ID 5 are returning me 12.

Comment: @Leo Edited my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Tryed this! It gave me the same amount (12 for 1st and 5 for 2nd). What make no sense for me is the counting of the TOTAL.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any overlapping posts? Try `$posts_c = new WP_Query(array('category__and'=>array(5,29,30)))`

Comment: Add `posts_per_page` in the WP_QUery array and try? `$posts_all = new WP_Query('cat=5&posts_per_page=-1');` Actually, use it in all your WP_Queries. Look at my edited answer

Comment: Wow! That worked!!!12 was the standard post per page. I would never thought about use -1.
Thak you, Munim!!